# Undefined method `images_path' (Carrierwave + Nested Resources)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm trying to make my Image model a child of my Listing model, using Railscast's Carrierwave tutorial as a starting point. I changed the routes but when I try to upload an image, going to this URL localhost:300/listings/1/images/new I get this error: **undefined method `images_path' for #<#:0x00000109abfd88>**

Any help? Thanks.

**image_controller.rb**

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_image, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

   def index
      # I changed this so the images would appear on localhost:300/listings/3/images
      # Don't know if it's the best way to accomplish that
      @images = Listing.find(params[:listing_id]).images
   end

   def new
      @image = Image.new(:listing_id => params[:listing_id])
   end

   def edit
   end

   def create
      @image = Image.new(image_params)

      respond_to do |format|
         if @image.save
            format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Image was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @image }
         else
            format.html { render action: 'new' }
            format.json { render json: @image.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
         end
      end
   end

   def update
      respond_to do |format|
         if @image.update(image_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @image, notice: 'Image was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
         else
            format.html { render action: 'edit' }
            format.json { render json: @image.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
         end
      end
   end

   def destroy
      @image.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
         format.html { redirect_to :back }
         format.json { head :no_content }
      end
   end

   private
      # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
      def set_image
         @image = Image.find(params[:id])
      end

      # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
      def image_params
         params.require(:image).permit(:file, :listing_id)
      end
end
```

**images.rb form**

```
<%= form_for [@listing, @image], :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
   <% if @image.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
         <h2><%= pluralize(@image.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this image from being saved:</h2>

         <ul>
         <% @image.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
         <% end %>
         </ul>
      </div>
   <% end %>

   <%= f.hidden_field :listing_id %>

   <div>
      <%= f.label :file, 'Upload Images' %>
      <%= f.file_field :file %>
   </div>

   <div>
      <%= f.submit %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not initialized `@listing` object in your controller, but used it in the view.

Make this change

```
def new
  @listing = Listing.find params[:listing_id]
  @image = Image.new(:listing_id => params[:listing_id])
end
```